# Cargar controlFX 9 en Scene Builder

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder, controlsfx

Tengo instalados los `ControlsFX` 8.40 y los he intentado actualizar a la versión 9 de `JavaFX` en el editor Scene Builder pero no se cargan. He probado a desinstalar la versión 8.40 pero tampoco me deja. Otro problema añadido que tengo es que cuando utilizo algún control de `ControlsFX`, al abrir el Scene Builder desde Netbeans me aparece un error y el fichero `fxml` no se abre, pero si cargo un fichero `fxml` directamente en Scene Builder si que se carga sin problemas.
A ver si alguien sabe por qué pasa todo eso. Gracias.

El error es el siguiente:

```
java.io.IOException: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/Users/ADP13/NetBeansProjects/Dieta/src/dieta/FórmulasGrasa.fxml

    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.load(FXOMLoader.java:92)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.<init>(FXOMDocument.java:82)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.<init>(FXOMDocument.java:97)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.EditorController.updateFxomDocument(EditorController.java:2384)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.EditorController.setFxmlTextAndLocation(EditorController.java:664)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.DocumentWindowController.loadFromFile(DocumentWindowController.java:384)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.performOpenFiles(SceneBuilderApp.java:566)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.lambda$handleOpenFilesAction$86(SceneBuilderApp.java:436)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/Users/ADP13/NetBeansProjects/Dieta/src/dieta/FórmulasGrasa.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2848)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(FXMLLoader.java:2692)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(FXMLLoader.java:2661)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2517)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.load(FXOMLoader.java:89)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.controlsfx.control.RangeSlider
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:530)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:2916)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2905)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2846)
    ... 16 more
```

Comment: Necesitas dar más informacion, como logs/errores. Mira [ask] para mejorar la calidad de la pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Probé a agregar acentos en un fxml que tenía y abrió sin problemas, así que el problema está en el contenido de tu fxml o de tu instalación de Java FX, desafortunadamente no podemos ayudarte por falta de detalles. Saludos.

Comment: Solo por si fuera el caso, [a veces no te encuentra controlfx porque no está el jar en el classpath al correr tu aplicación](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25602375/unable-to-import-org-controlsfx)